# Solutions of pde $u_t+tu_x=0$ with condition $u(0,t)=f(t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Consider the PDE $$u_t+tu_x=0 \\ u(0,t)=f(t)$$ We have that general solution is $u(x,t)=\phi(\frac{t^2}{2}-x)$. Notice that the solution is not unique since there is a family of characteristic curves that pass through the origin.

If $t>0, $ then there is no solution unless $\frac{t^2}{2}-x=c>0$

I don't understand why there won't be solutions unless $\frac{t^2}{2}-x=c>0$.

Why  $\frac{t^2}{2}-x=c<0$ doesn't work?

Could someone explain this please?

Comment: don't understand the upvotes with no answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote : $u(0,t)=f(x)$ which is non-sens since $u(0,t)$ is function of $t$, not of $x$. So, I suppose that the correct equation is :
$$u_t+tu_x=0 \\ u(0,t)=f(t)$$
$u(x,t)=\phi(\frac{t^2}{2}-x)$ is correct.

Condition : $u(0,t)=\phi(\frac{t^2}{2})=f(t)$

Let $X=\frac{t^2}{2}\geq 0\quad$ thus $\quad t=\sqrt{2X}\quad$ and so $\quad \phi(X)=f(\sqrt{2X})$

Now, the function $\phi(X)$ is determined. Putting it into the above general solution where $X=\frac{t^2}{2}-x$ leads to :

$$u(x,t)=f\left(\sqrt{2\left(\frac{t^2}{2}-x\right)}\right)$$
$$u(x,t)=f\left(\sqrt{t^2-2x}\right)\quad \text{in case of}\quad t^2-2x\geq 0$$

Comment: Ok, so $t^2-2x$  must be greater or equal to $0$ because the $f$ function is  defined as $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, right?

Comment: And it doesn't matter how $t$ is, can be positive or negative or even $0$, the only necessary condition for the final solution $u(t,x)$ is to have $t^2-2x$ greater or equal to $0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Would you mind correct your question for $u(0,t)=f(t)$ or $u(x,0)=f(x)$ , but not $u(0,t)=f(x)$.

Comment: Sure, sorry :-(

Comment: $u(x,t)=f\left(\sqrt{2x-t^2}\right)$ is also solution of the PDE. But at $x=0$ and $t\neq 0$ ,  $\sqrt{2x-t^2}$ is not real.